# Como chamar dentro de um map uma função que retorna uma Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, map

Estou consumindo uma API e me deparei com esse problema. Estou usando um map para criar um novo campo em um array de objetos e inserir o dado com base em uma consulta no banco. Já de buguei e verifiquei que está retornando os valores desejados na consulta porém não consigo tirar da Promisse fica aparecendo "[object Promise]". Já tentei colocar then e catch ou async e await no map e não deu certo.

```
allusuarios(){
  return this.usuarios.map( prop => ({
    ...prop,
     usuario_nome: Usuario.show(prop.usuario_id).then(resp => {
          return resp.data.nome
     })
  }))
},
```

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar.

@EDIT

Ainda não consegui resolver, testei usando async e await e o retorno agora vem somente um proxy array vazio. Vou deixar as funções utilizadas abaixo caso alguém possa ajudar

```
  async allUsuarios(){
   return await Promise.all(this.usuarios.map(async (prop) => ({
    ...prop,
    usuario_nome: await Usuario.show(prop.usuario_id)
   })));
 }


show:(usuario_id) =>{
  return http.get(`usuarios/${predio_id}`);
}
```

a Função "show" apenas está em um arquivo separado

Comment: Já tentou usar `Promise.all`? Isso basicamente fará com que todas as promessas dentro do array sejam resolvidas. Aí você pode dar um `await` (na promessa que o `Promise.all` retorna) e acessar cada elemento resolvido do array.

Comment: Olá, tentei algo na linha que você comentou e o compilador diz que Promises.all não é reconhecido na função. print do código: http://prntscr.com/1xndyez

Comment: tente colocar async no método map e await onde retorna a promisse e também crie uma variável para armazenar o map já q ele retorna uma nova array

Answer (score 0):

Isso é porque `Usuario.show` retorna uma `Promise`. Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```js
// Note que agora allUsuarios é uma função
// assíncrona, indicando que ela retorna uma Promise.
// A keyword async também permite que usemos o comando await
async function allUsuarios() {
  // array de promises
  const promises = this.usuarios.map(usuario => Usuario.show(usuario.usuario_id))

  // esperamos todas as promises completarem
  const resultados = await Promise.all(promises)
  
  // pronto, só iterar e montar o retorno
  const usuariosComNome = []
  for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
    usuariosComNome.push({ ...usuarios[i], usuario_nome: resultados[i].data.nome })
  }

  return usuariosComNome
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, tentei a solução que você propôs e continuo com o erro. Os dados continuam dentro de uma Promise, segue o print: http://prntscr.com/1xnmu1z

Comment: Lembre-se que ao chamar `allUsuarios` você também deve esperar ela completar, usando `await`. Tipo `await allUsuarios()`

Comment: testei com async created() do vue

Answer (score -3):

good. I had this problem, I fixed it this way.
It's not pure JavaScript, but it might help you

private async getAllInfoProject(): Promise {

```
const InfoProjetos = await this.infoProjectRepository.find();

const ArrayMap = await Promise.all(
    InfoProjetos.map(async (infoProject) => {
      let completeData: any;
  
      if (infoProject.type === "ict") {
        const ict = await this.ictProjectRepository.findById(infoProject.ict_or_startup_id);
        if (ict) {
          completeData = {
            infoProject,
            correlatedData: ict,
          };
          return completeData;
        }
      } else if (infoProject.type === "Startup") {
        const startup = await this.startupProjectRepository.findById(infoProject.ict_or_startup_id);
        if (startup) {
          completeData = {
            infoProject,
            correlatedData: startup,
          };
          return completeData;
        }
      }
  
      return null; // or throw an error if necessary
    })
  );
  
  const ArrayDados = ArrayMap.filter(result => result !== null);
  
// const resultados = await Promise.all(ArrayMap)
console.log(ArrayMap)

return ArrayDados;
```

}

Comment: Esse é o [pt.so], como o nome diz esse site é dedicado aos usuários de língua portuguesa. Favor [edit] a resposta e adequar o idioma.